# Problems with FB.XFBML.parse()

Tags: jquery, facebook, load, comments, ready

I'm writing a website with a deep Facebook integration; via js I call a php file which loads an external web page with some FB comments.

```
$('#post{$id1}').load('php/loadPost.php?id={$id1} #single-post');";
```

But usually it doesn't load comments as it should (I would also like to know why it doesn't, but it's not the point now).  In the .js file there is

```
$("#insertHere").on("click", ".well", function(){
     FB.XFBML.parse(this);
});
```

so that when I click on that particular post, FB comments will load; is there a way to make this happen when the single ".well" div loads? I tried both ready() and waypoint() with no luck.

Thank-you!

edit: I use on() because all "well" divs are created dynamically thanks to the load() function, just so you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this if it helps:

```
$('#post{$id1}').load('php/loadPost.php?id={$id1} #single-post', function() {
  //alert('Load was performed.');
  FB.XFBML.parse();
});
```

Comment: it was that easy! Well, thank-you very much, you made my day! Have a nice Sunday!